# php artisan migrate with sqlite throws error, database is locked

Tags: laravel, sqlite, laravel-artisan, artisan-migrate

I was trying to play a bit with Laravel and SQLite but whenever I run `php artisan migrate` I always get the same error: `Illuminate\Database\QueryException  : SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 5 database is locked (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" integer not null primary key autoincrement, "migration" varchar not null, "batch" integer not null))`

I tried all the options, tried running the command as `sudo php artisan migrate` but still no luck, As well I set directory and file permissions to 777 and still got the same error.

I'm running Laravel on vagrant box where host is Windows 10 and guest is Ubuntu 16.04 and using recommended synchronization method `sync_type: smb`.

I know that I can use MySQL or other drivers, I was just curios to see if anyone knows the why.

By the way i tried `fuser database.sqlite` and it returns empty which means no other process is using it.

What I notices is that when i run `php artisan migrate` a new file is created `database.sqlite-journal` which is synchronized on the host as well and I was thinking if it is possible that the IDE PhpStrom or the Host (Windows) is using the temporary `database.sqlite-journal` and locking it?!

Answer (score 1):

OK, I found the issue but I don't know the reason?

I switched `sync_type` for synchronized folder between host (Windows) and guest (Ubuntu) from **smb** to **default** and everything worked perfectly.

If anyone knows why `sync_type: smb` causes this can post it.